# How to access JSON object with typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, json, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I want to access to a DB of People in Json with Twitter Typeahead. But I don´t know hoy to obtain a substring, it doesnt display anything.
I want to obtain people.name, people.patern and people.matern.
 This is my javaScript:

```
var jsonPeople = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('people'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: 'js/json/people.json'
});

$('#name').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'name',
  limit: 20,
  displayKey: 'people.name',
  source: jsonPeople
});

$('#patern').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'patern',
  limit: 20,
  displayKey: 'people.patern',
  source: jsonPeople
});

$('#matern').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'matern',
  limit: 20,
  displayKey: 'people.matern',
  source: jsonPeople
});
```

Json File (people.json)

```
{"people": [{
"name": "Marlon",
"patern": "Contla",
"matern": "Rodríguez",
"area": "Riesgos",
"image": "mark.jpg",
"id": "123"
},
{
"name": "José Luis",
"patern": "Gutierrez",
"matern": "Guerrero",
"area": "Adquisiciones",
"image": "jose.jpg",
"id": "124"
},
{
"name": "Eduardo",
"patern": "Guzmán",
"matern": "Lopez",
"area": "Banca Comercial",
"image": "lalo.jpg",
"id": "125"
}
]}
```

Comment: You may want to look at the transform in the prefetch object: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#prefetch